# Ansible - how to create condition for role dependency

Tags: ansible

If you need to have a role dependency run in certain conditions, you can use jinja templating.
This will cause one role to run if a condition is true/met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In role/meta/main.yml add:

```
---
  dependencies:
  - role: "{{ 'my_role' if some_condition else '' }}"
```

example:

```
---
  dependencies:
  - role: "{{ 'aws_start' if varx is defined else 'awx_deploy' }}"
```